# Chrome OS Notification Shelf Icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, google-chrome-os, web-notifications

How can I create a shelf icon for Chrome OS notifications? Using web notifications would be preferred, but using extension notifications is also acceptable.

Update: It seems that appIconMaskUrl of extension notifications adds an icon to the shelf, but the icon is an all white square.

This image demonstrates the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/display-a-notification#icon

Comment: @AndroidNoobie That demo does not set the icon in the shelf. It just shows as a number.